# Formula to check if the domain and website matches or partially matches?

Tags: excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I have a formula that tells if the email domain and website are same or not and if it contains certain syllables.
=(IFERROR(IF((RIGHT(N2,LEN(N2)-FIND("@",N2)))=(SUBSTITUTE(K2,"www.","")),"","NOT MATCHED!"),(if((SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Checklist!H:H,N2)))>0)=TRUE,"NOT MATCHED",""))))

I am trying to make this a bit more dynamic: website- google.com email domain- @googlemail.com, the formula will consider this as a match, as google is present in both of them.

I tried to give it a with this formula
=IF({LEFT(REPLACE(N2,1,FIND("@",N2),""),FIND(".",REPLACE(N2,1,FIND("@",N2),""))-1)})=(SUBSTITUTE(K2,"www.",""),"","NOT MATCHED!"),if((SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(Checklist!H:H,N2)))>0)=TRUE,"NOT MATCHED","")

But doesn't work, and I can't seem to figure out what is the issue.

Comment: If you would provide a copy of your sheet, shared and editable by all, it will make it easier for people to respond to your question.  Without seeing your data in H:H and N2, it is unclear what we are working with.

Comment: But I'm not quite clear how you are using the array - at the start of your IF statement, beginning with {LEFT - to compare to (SUBSTITUTE(K2,"www.","").  What is meant to be in the array, and is that a valid comparison?

Comment: Apologies for the late response. Where is the spreadsheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16-TNMgRg9FR8n_Mk2nLYQIwajYUhiG3ZrCB7w1_YRo4/edit#gid=0